# NetLogo: hubnet-broadcast-message adds unwanted newline

Tags: netlogo, hubnet

When sending a message to HubNet clients using hubnet-broadcast-message or hubnet-send-message a newline is added. This does not happen when broadcasting a message using the HubNet Control Center.

Example:

```
hubnet-broadcast-message "test"
hubnet-broadcast-message "test2"
```

Shows in the clients as:

```
test

test2
(*another newline here*)
```

The Broadcast Message option in Hubnet Control Center gives:

```
3:28:19   <Leader> test
3:28:21   <Leader> test2
```

My question is how do I broadcast a message from my code without the added newline? Currently only the last message is visible to the clients due to the newline.

Comment: One workaround I have found is clearing the output using hubnet-broadcast-clear-output and resending all messages at once with "\n" between each message. This is not ideal however as it still adds an unwanted newline, be it only one.

Comment: sounds like a bug — I'd suggest opening a ticket at https://github.com/netlogo/netlogo/issues

Comment: @SethTisue Thank you, I have reported it.

Comment: for the record, the ticket is https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/836